# Logging in setters

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have a non-mandatory filed, that has setters and getters.
Let's assume that is is phoneNumber in User object.

In setter I would like to make it like this:

```
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    if (PhoneNumberValidator.isPhoneNumberStructureValid(phoneNumber)) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

I don't like the idea that we do nothing in case phone number is not valid. Maybe it makes sence to log about it? I'm not sure because for some reason I consider logging in setters to be a bad code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should avoid mixing setters with validation rules.
As setters are often dumb, if the developer has not developed the setter, one should goes in the method to guess the validation rule.

2) You should also avoid logging in the setter because it makes less readable your code and it encourages scattered debug logs that is a bad practice.

3) If the phone has to be valid and that you valid it, you should perform it before trying setting the field. It is much more readable to understand the validation logic. 
Besides, you should try to group all validations in a same method or a same class. It eases the understanding of the set of validation rules.
And it would be a very good place to log not respected validation rules if you think that it is relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that most of developers do use setters just because they are used to create setters (and cause some frameworks require this). But it is absolutely  not what setters were designed for. They were designed for encapsulation and validation - so that you won't have an opportunity set any incorrect value to field directly.

So I disagree with your idea that validation login shouldn't be used in setters. But I agree, that it's often not used in setters.

Comment: To separate the validation you could use Basic annotations (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm) if you are in an jee environment.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this annotation would raise an exception, but I don't want such behavior as it's not a mandatory parameter and I don't want to "fail" in this case.

Comment: @Иван Николайчук if the design of the setter is known and normal in your case, well. Nevertheless it causes a readability problem since scattering the form validation responsibility in multiple setter makes validation rules more hard to identify for the developer who reads the code. Sorry, I find this design very error prone. Making a check when you modify a specific value is good but if you have to check a set of fields for a specific user case, you should have visible rules for this usecase.

Comment: Well, yes, I agree about readability. But it looks verry dummy for me that setters are used everywhere, but there is no need for them. Just tried to find any useful point in using setter.

Comment: I understand totally your point. You could try to remove them when they are not required. If the property cannot be modified once it is loaded you could and you should even remove the setter and use a constructor or an fluent api to value the property during the object construction. Otherwise sorry but indeed the dumb setters are not very different from a direct access to the private field that could be public.

Answer (score 1):

I would raise an exception if phone number is not valid.  Although it's a non mandatory property but having an invalid value should not be an option.

Absence of phone number should be treaded specially in layers above this code.  For example request sent from client to server could have a flag.

You can also keep validation outside your class,  have a builder pattern build your model.

Comment: "but having an invalid value should not be an option". 
Sure. Thats why we don't set invalid param, but just log that there was an attempt to set an invalid param.
Rasing exception sounds too radically for me in this case.

Comment: You could catch the exception in layer above and log it.

Comment: Well, it's too annoying, because in this case exception should be checked and should exist in method-signature. I think it would look strange for setter and what is worse: it has to be handled on each setter call.

Comment: It should be unchecked exception. Should be same exception raised by all optional setters.  You should unit test to ensure that exception are caught.  However I still feel that validation should not be part of this class.  It should always assume to have correct value

Comment: If it should be an unchecked exception it would look very strange that it is catched and logged on each setter call. It's not what unchecked exceptions are designed for.

Comment: You would call your setters together and catch it once. The fact that you are doing validation in your setter method means that validation could fail.  If it is an exceptional case for you  then unchecked exception should be used otherwise checked exception should be raised.  A separate validator could have meant that you could return validation result in your method return.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GauravJ that if you have a validation in your `setPhoneNumber`, then you need to `throw` an exception. However, we might want to be able to set phone numbers even without validation in case we know it surely that the phone number we are going to set is correct. Let's imagine a case when on an admin panel we are specifying that a company has moved to another country which will trigger a prefix change of the phone numbers of its employees, who could be many and data is loaded from a trusted database. In this case validation would be useless and it will reduce performance. We need to be able to set the value with or without validation, so:

```
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, boolean validate) {
    if (PhoneNumberValidator.isPhoneNumberStructureValid(phoneNumber)) {
        setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    } else {
        //throw your exception and log it here
    }
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

So, when you know there is no need for validation, call the one with a single parameter and when you need validation, call the one which validates. There is nothing wrong in having validation and logging in a setter as long as you have an overload which can be used when these are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid validation code inside your setter by using a dedicated class to represent phone numbers. Your setter would then accept only valid PhoneNumber objects, by construction. It would, therefore, be the constructor of the PhoneNumber class or a factory method that would validate the phone number. I think it all depends on how often you manipulate phone numbers.

```
public class PhoneNumber {

     public static PhoneNumber fromString(String text) throws InvalidPhoneNumber {
          // Perform the validation here
     }

     // How you want to represent a phone number
     private int countryCode;
     private int areaCode;
     private ...

     PhoneNumber(int country, int area, ...) { 
          this.countryCode = country;
          this.areaCode = area;
          // ...
     }

}

// ...
// Your original setter
public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

This class may also later help avoid duplication if other methods are needed on PhoneNumber, such as getting the country or area codes for instance.